# Are there any drawbacks making iOS 14 Logger static?

Tags: ios, swift, logging

This question may very well be of little use, but with the new releases came a new `Logger` struct that looks awesome. You can learn more about it [in this WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10168/).

I was implementing it like they presented in one of the slides, making a logger property in my class and accessing it from my methods. But at some point, I wanted to log something inside a closure and I had to [weak self] my call to the logger. To me, that's a little inconvenient, so I've decided to put my logger inside a static logger property such as:

```swift
private static let logger = Logger(subsystem: "com.example.Logging", category: "Subject")

func aMethod() {
    // So I can call it this way…
    Self.logger.log("Something")
    // This could be a closure, I could still access my Logger using Self
}
```

Are there any drawbacks (performance, memory, bugs?) doing this instead of making the logger a regular property?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `[weak self]` since you are not referring to `self`. The `logger` is a static variable and you are accessing it from the type itself using `Self` (with the capital 'S').

Some expensive classes like `Formatters`, `Loggers` or etc are better to instantiate **just once**. That could be the main reason that some people implement them as static variables or singleton objects or etc.

Comment: There may have been a misunderstanding. I needed `[weak self]` at first, when my logger was declared as `let logger = Logger(…)`, i.e: when it wasn't static yet.

Will the logger be instantiated just once when marked `static` or will it be instantiated every time it's accessed? I have to admit that kind of things are sometimes still unclear to me.

Comment: `static` variables are accessible from the type and even can not be overridden. So just **Just once** is a correct sentence.

Comment: Alright! Thank you very much. I didn't get that `static` variables were persisted in memory as long as they are declared with `=` instead of `{  }`.